# VB Auto populate datagridview from datatable

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to have a datagrieview populate directly from a datable ? Below is what I am trying in the form load.  Basically I want it to show all the columns this query returns automatically

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    Dim titleSQLStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Titles ORDER BY YearPublished DESC"
    daYears = New OleDbDataAdapter(titleSQLStr, connStr)
    daYears.Fill(dtYears)
    cboYearsFillBy.DataSource = dtYears
    cboYearsFillBy.DisplayMember = "YearPublished"
    cboYearsFillBy.ValueMember = "YearPublished"
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = daYears
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Change it to `DataGridView1.DataSource = dtYears`

Comment: Derrrf.... Feel free to punch me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtYears
```